# Local Notification in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uilocalnotification

I know that when a local notification is arrived and when user taps on that notification, application opens and didReceivedLocalNotification method is called from AppDelegate.

What i want to ask is that what method is called when a local notification arrives and before user taps the notification.

Comment: What do you mean "arrives"? You are the one that set it, you know when it's set, no?

Comment: yeah i know i set it, but when it appears on screen what method is called?

Comment: On screen? Since your App needs to be not in foreground, that's the OS that manages it.

Comment: I would recommend to read [the official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html), maybe.

Comment: yes my app is not in foreground yet, it will only be in foreground when a user taps on the notification but before tapping the notification what method is called?

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't have handler in process data for local notifications, as for remote notifications, function:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```